# Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver

Tags: ati

I had the beta drivers running previously and after a standard update it stopped working.
What I've tried so far:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx*
```

Then downloaded drivers from Amd website and unzipped it and ran:

```
sudo ./amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13-4-x86.x86_64.run --buildpkg Ubuntu/trusty
sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
```

After this the Ubuntu [BinaryDriverHowTo/AMD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) guide wants to make this:

```
aticonfig --initial
```

and it returns:

```
Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver.
aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

The adapter is 280x and as said, it worked previously with the same drivers and with the same installation procedure.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should probably not ask this question here. Ubuntu 14.04 OS is off topic.

Comment: I'm having the same problem on saucy, so might not be related to the dev version. I also seem to have lost symlinks to amdconfig etc, but get the same output as above when I run them from /usr/lib/fglrx/bin

Comment: "Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver.". Does that file exist? What are the permissions if it does? if it does not:  extract the file from the tar file and copy it over to /etc/ati/.  And then try again :)

Comment: I have the same issue.  I have installed and removed the drivers about 4 times at this stage but still I get the same error above even though driver seems to be install correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Use this commands as root:

```
/usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibGL amd # or /usr/lib/fglrx/switchlibglx amd
reboot
```

And after rebooting, try to execute

```
aticonfig --initial
```

Comment: This command does all the setup that Ken Wolf's answer does manually. There's also no need to reboot before running `aticonfig --initial`.

Answer (score 4):

I managed to get it working by creating a few of the missing symbolic links:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/aticonfig /usr/bin/aticonfig
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/ati/ /etc/ati
```

I was then able to run `aticonfig` as normal

Answer (score 0):

I had such message too just after a (re)installation of ATI driver (Catalyst). Try the following:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

---

My system:

Graphics: ASUS R7240-SL-2GD3-L (AMD Radeon R7 240)
OS: KUbuntu 14.04
Graphics driver: AMD Catalyst™ 15.5 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver

Comment: P.S. 

Then I (via deb package manager - Muon) lock versions for  these packages: fglrx, fglrx-core, fglrx-amdcccle. This because a normal update procedure brings a system into a state where graphics driver does not function (i. e., system can not switch to a graphic mode on loading). I found this way experimentally.

Answer (score 0):

I am on 16.04 (xenial) but had the same problems and probably the same solution. The only solution I found was to manually unpack the `fglrx-core` debian package and copy the `/etc/ati/control` and `/etc/ati/atiapfxx` files from that unpacked directory to the correct locations using sudo.

The deb packages that are installed end up in `/var/cache/apt/archives/`

So I moved to some new directory and did

```
dpkg-deb -x /var/cache/apt/archives/fglrx-core<some version number>.deb .
sudo cp etc/ati/atiapfxx etc/ati/control /etc/ati/
```

After that I was able to use aticonfig and also amdcccle started to work.