# Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver 14.04

Tags: drivers, ati, proprietary

Please reopen this question, as 14.04 is now official and no longer a beta version, and the problem still exists:

[Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445954/unable-to-open-etc-ati-control-please-reinstall-the-driver)

Comment: I have the same issue.  Tried reinstall / removing the drivers lots of times now and to no avail.