# Problems with fglrx driver on AMD Radeon 8000M series on Trusty

Tags: drivers, 14.04, ati, radeon, fglrx

I have tried installing proprietary drivers from the "Software & Updates dialog" and also from ATI's latest driver [page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/Latest-LINUX-Beta-Driver.aspx).

The problem I am facing is that the binaries aren't in the path, and trying to run them with the full path gives me the following error.

```
atoulan@atoulan-laptop:~$ sudo /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/aticonfig 
Unable to open /etc/ati/control, please reinstall the driver.
/usr/lib/fglrx/bin/aticonfig: No supported adapters detected
```

Here is the output from lspci:

```
atoulan@atoulan-laptop:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
```

and uname:

```
atoulan@atoulan-laptop:~$ uname -a
Linux atoulan-laptop 3.13.0-29-lowlatency #53-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Wed Jun 4 21:27:51 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

According to AMD's page my card should be supported by this driver. Of course every time I try out a new driver I purge the old ones.

Can anyone tell me how to install this driver properly ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this, as mentioned in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/445954/unable-to-open-etc-ati-control-please-reinstall-the-driver):
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/bin/aticonfig /usr/bin/aticonfig`
`sudo ln -s /usr/lib/fglrx/etc/ati/ /etc/ati`
You may just  miss these symbolic links.

Comment: I have been banging my head against the wall because of this. Truly thank you :)

Comment: Although this helped me get a little further, the resulting xorg config would not work for me. I had to reinstall the driver directly, without building packages, for it to work.